# wait for multiple elements change in tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Can we wait for multiple element to change asynchronously in tampermonkey? right now my code only implemented to monitor for one element change:

`waitForKeyElements("span.current-item.m-right-xs.show-gt-md.ng-binding.ng-scope.flex:first", getorg, true);`

Thanks.

Comment: Add `, .second-selector` to the selector inside the quotes.